# Serilog Object Logging returning null

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

Code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(Invoice data)
{
    Log.Information("Data: {@data}", data);
    // do somethings below
}
```

I'm logging to Elastic Search. When i reviewed the log in Kibana the output is like this

> messageTemplate:Data: {@data} message:Data: null
>   @timestamp:August 16th 2019, 22:53:32.039 level:Information
>   fields.data: -
>   fields.ActionId:3ab52c6a-e917-4b56-bb76-5f28af8292be

Any pointer as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting nobody answered this, but it looks like there's no Serilog issue here except that your Invoice data is actually null.